# What is the probability of reaching the mathematical end of 2048?

Tags: probability-theory

Ok, I'll start off by saying that my knowledge of code is non-existent. Next, I calculated the largest possible tile that can be reached in the game 2048 which is 131072. I want to calculate the probability of reaching this tile. However I'm struggling. I'm unsure how I would translate the human decision-making into a probability problem.

PS. I am aware that my question is similar to other questions that have been posted before. But I read them and they did not help me.

Comment: I don't think that human dicision making belongs to the topics of this site. If you are asking however for the probability of reaching the largest tile with perfect play, this could be discussed mathematically.

Comment: Yes, I would like to discuss this mathematically. I want to exclude (if possible) the human aspect entirely